# Portable charging device

Tags: battery, hardware-rec, charging

I have several devices that charge by USB, that I'd like to keep charged at all times.

I've used my laptop in the past, put it in the lowest possible power setting, but it still gets hot, and is using more power than necessary and only lasts 2 hours.

Is there a device that can be used to charge USB gadgets, that is essentially a large battery with USB connections?

I'm not looking for a hub that requires a connection to a computer, I want a standalone charging device that has a large enough battery to charge multiple devices.

Ideally something with a car voltage adapter for charging itself would be optimal.

Would keep it in my backpack/suitcase and devices plugged in until I need them would be optimal usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some car battery jump starters have USB inputs.
[Example](http://www.sears.com/shc/s/p_10153_12605_02871987000P?prdNo=6)

Also, you could get a solar charger.
[Example](http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=SOLAR-MOBILE-CHARGER-2&cpc=SCH)

Comment: First one is a good idea for multiple reasons.

Second one is just plain cool. Not sure which one I'll get!

Comment: Since they technically perform different tasks, you could get both!

Answer (score 2):

This is my favourite as it can also power laptops as well as having a 5V USB socket:

[Ultimate-Netbook U20 External Power Pack for Laptop and PDA](http://www.smartphonegurus.com/forums/topic/6741-review-ultimate-netbook-u20-external-power-pack-for-laptop-and-pda/)

Answer (score 1):

There are many such products, this is one of them.

[http://www.amazon.com/Duracell-Instant-Charger-Compatible-Devices/dp/B0016Y9R6C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0016Y9R6C)

This one has a car charger too:

[http://www.amazon.com/Macally-PowerGo-Battery-Charger-White/dp/B002PAQYDU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002PAQYDU)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that some USB devices (my Sony E-Reader for one) need to be connected to a PC with the correct drivers/software installed before they will charge. Also stuff like ipods can be finicky.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are ways of charging USB devices without using a computer. The cheapest, most common method is to use a

1. **USB AC adapter**

which is basically a plug you plug into the wall socket with a USB port on it to plug your device into it. You can check out products like 1000mA USB AC Adapter from a company like **DealExtreme** which is a gadgets selling and service company.

Have you checked out

2. **MintyBoost**

It is a **battery-powered** USB charger. So you can use this incase of power loss.

All the best.